# Which struct is used to extract information from a registry value data of type REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

## Background

According to my search on Google, when the value type given by **RegQueryValueEx()** or **NtQueryValueKey()** is `REG_RESOURCE_LIST` or `REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST`, the data received in
the *lpData* parameter is a pointer to a variable of type [CM_RESOURCE_LIST struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_resource_list) or [IO_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_resource_requirements_list) respectively.

I have managed to extract information from the value data of type `REG_RESOURCE_LIST` and `REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST` using the mentioned structs.

## Question

Which struct is used for a value type `REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR`?

I have tried to extract information from the value data of the following registry location using [CM_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_full_resource_descriptor) with no success:

```
Key Path  : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System
Value Name: Configuration Data
Value Type: REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This Windows 7 sample should provide you with [example code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/registry/RegExplorer.c) you are seeking

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
case REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR:
    LoadString(hInst, IDS_REGFULLDESC, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer));
    SetDlgItemText (hDlg, IDE_VALUE1, lpBuffer);
    break;
```

Comment: in this example no any code which handle `REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR` type

Comment: @YePhIcK, the example code only read the binary data received in the _lpData_ parameter into a string.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was already on the right track. 
To extract information from a registry value data of type `REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR`, just parse the binary data as if it was a [CM_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_full_resource_descriptor).

However, there is one thing to note:

If size of a value data is only **16 bytes**, this indicates the value data does not include the ***PartialDescriptors*** member of [CM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_LIST struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_partial_resource_list). Alternatively, we can check whether the value of ***Count*** member of [CM_PARTIAL_RESOURCE_LIST struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_cm_partial_resource_list) is 0.

Hope this helps.